# Convergence of a series using the ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Can you help me with the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^{n(n+1)}$$

I tried the ratio limit but i couldn't obtain the limit, do you have an idea?, the limit of the ratio test is
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n} \right)^{n(n+1)} \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{(n+1)(n+2)}$$
I review it on Wolframalpha, and it's suppose to converge to $\frac{1}{e}$ but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the root test?

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n})^{1/n} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} = e^{-1} < 1
\end{align*}

Thus the proposed series converges, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using the ratio test
$$a_n=\left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^{n(n+1)}\implies \log(a_n)=n(n+1)\log\left(1- \frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$ Now, Taylor series
$$\log(a_n)=-n-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6 n}-\frac{1}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Apply for $a_{n+1}$ and continue with Taylor series
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-1-\frac{1}{6 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1} } {a_n }=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n) }=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{6 e n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$